# How to remove libreoffice?

Tags: software-installation

I installed Libreoffice from the official web site. Te application looks bad, with some sections dark, and letters in gray. Unconfortable to work with. How can I fully remove the isntallation? I executed

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

Didn't work.

In the directory where all DEBS were stored, and from which I executed "dpkg -i", I executed:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r *.deb
```

I get an error in Sanish, which translation is

> error: you must specify the packets by their own names, not citing the
>   names of the files in which they come

Comment: You really should use Elementary store to install Libreoffice. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I used Synaptic to remove it. All fine

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```